# adding toggle buttons dynamically after adding click one button it will effect on another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi am adding toggle buttons dynamically when click on a button. But after adding I clicked on one button it is working fine after clicking other button then it will effecting first one only.

please help me!

HTML code:

```
<div id='test'>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">
        Add toggle button
    </button>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
 #switchdiv
{
clear: both;
margin:1px;
}

input.switch:empty
{
margin-left: -999px;
}

input.switch:empty ~ label
 {
position: relative;
float: left;
line-height: 1.6em;
text-indent: 4em;
margin: 0.2em 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
 }

input.switch:empty ~ label:before, 
input.switch:empty ~ label:after
{
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
content: ' ';
width: 3.6em;
background-color: #c33;
border-radius: 0.3em;
box-shadow: inset 0 0.2em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
     transition: all 100ms ease-in;
 }

input.switch:empty ~ label:after
{
width: 1.4em;
top: 0.1em;
bottom: 0.1em;
margin-left: 0.1em;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 0.15em;
box-shadow: inset 0 -0.2em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

 input.switch:checked ~ label:before
{
background-color: #393;
 }

input.switch:checked ~ label:after
{
margin-left: 2.1em;
}
```

javaScript code:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var element = $('#test');
    var toggle_button = '<div id="switchdiv">\
        <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" name="switch1" class="switch" visible="false"/>\
        <label for="switch1">first switch</label>\
        </div>';
    element.append(toggle_button);
});
```

Comment: Can you add code of `myFunction()`

Comment: Hi tushar , $('button').click( function()  this is for click event because we have only one button so directly  I added like that.

Comment: @GVR please checkout my answer, i fixed your issue

Answer (score 1):

You have written click event two times for the same button. One in `onclick="myFunction()"` and the other one is

```
$('button').click(function() {

});
```

So, correct that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, your generated input had the same id, so all i did is declaring a `id` variable that will be incremented on every click, I then used it in your `input` and `label`. I changed only your `javascript`, everything else is still the same.

```js
var id = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
    var element = $('#test');
    var toggle_button = '<div id="switchdiv">\
        <input type="checkbox" id="switch' + id + '" name="switch' + id + '" class="switch" visible="false"/>\
        <label for="switch' + id + '">first switch</label>\
        </div>';
    element.append(toggle_button);
    id++;
});
```

```css
 #switchdiv
{
clear: both;
margin:1px;
}

input.switch:empty
{
margin-left: -999px;
}

input.switch:empty ~ label
 {
position: relative;
float: left;
line-height: 1.6em;
text-indent: 4em;
margin: 0.2em 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
 }

input.switch:empty ~ label:before, 
input.switch:empty ~ label:after
{
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
content: ' ';
width: 3.6em;
background-color: #c33;
border-radius: 0.3em;
box-shadow: inset 0 0.2em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
     transition: all 100ms ease-in;
 }

input.switch:empty ~ label:after
{
width: 1.4em;
top: 0.1em;
bottom: 0.1em;
margin-left: 0.1em;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 0.15em;
box-shadow: inset 0 -0.2em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

 input.switch:checked ~ label:before
{
background-color: #393;
 }

input.switch:checked ~ label:after
{
margin-left: 2.1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">
        Add toggle button
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: @GVR  you're welcome. don't forget to click the check on the left hand-side if this answer satisfy you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with [ID](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) selector, Add the below code and try.

```
var id = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
    var element = $('#test');    
    var toggle_button = '<div id="switchdiv">\
        <input type="checkbox" id="switch1'+id+'" name="switch1" class="switch" visible="false"/>\
        <label for="switch1'+id+'">first switch</label>\
        </div>';
    element.append(toggle_button);
    id++
});
```